# handleRemoteNowPlayingActivity not being called

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to show NowPlayingView on Apple Watch when I play music on an app on iOS.

As described in the documentation when turning on music on iOS, this opens the application on WatchOS and the `handleRemoteNowPlayingActivity` should fire in the `WKExtensionDelegate`. All methods of this delegate are fired but not `handleRemoteNowPlayingActivity`.

What's wrong?